# virtual box's nat network isn't working on 16.04 ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox

I'm using nat network on virtual box's virtual machine which is running ubuntu server 14.

And I set nat network 10.0.1.0/24. But, in the guest OS(VM), I ran command `ifconfig`. Then, it's IP is 10.0.2.4, rather 10.0.1.x. What's happening on this?

I tried many times doing deleting making VMS. But results are same. Is this bug?

And I also tried dhcp and static.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the OS Guest to be on the 10.0.1.x network, you'll need to set your Virtualbox network setting to "Bridged Adapter". Shutdown the Guest to change this setting.

Cheers, Al